Numbering of an equation does not show up with \pause and showonlyrefs
I have a tex file
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\hypersetup{
  hypertexnames=false,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B ,  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F , \label{eq1} \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{theorem} \label{thm1}
If A then B.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}

We have \eqref{eq1}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Could you explain why the numbering of E = F does not show up? I expect that it should show up in slides 2 and 3 where there is equation E = F.

You can use \label<...>{..} to specify the label for specific overlays:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B ,  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F , \label<2->{eq1} \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{theorem} \label{thm1}
If A then B.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1}.

\end{frame}


\end{document}



Could you explain how to tackle the case where I use We have \eqref{eq1} and \zcref{thm1}. I have tried \label<2->{thm1} but to no avail.

@Akira If you have a new question on how to enable numbering for theorems, please ask a new question.

You are right. Please see my new question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732721/jump-by-zcref-is-not-correct-with-pause

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz s/\label<2->{eq1}/\label<2>{eq1}/g to avoid the multiply defined labels.  ;-)

@gusbrs I think it looks strange if the equation number suddenly vanishes on the 3rd overlay

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are right, I hadn't thought of that... And, yeah, the warning does stem on how zref-clever uses the label hook here, and not on the standard operation. But I don't see how to do it differently, since \zlabel (and the internal zref-clever actually uses) have no support for the overlay argument.

@gusbrs Easy solution: people should just stop using overlays :P

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :-D
