Jump by \zcref is not correct with \pause
I have a tex file
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B ,  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F , \label<2->{eq1} \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{theorem} \label{thm1}
If A then B.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1} and \zcref{thm1}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Could you explain why the jump by \zcref{thm1} is not correct. It leads to slide 1 instead of slide 3.

It does not make a lot of sense to make a numerical reference if your theorems aren't numbered.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i meant the jump...

Specify a suitable overlay number for the label?

\label<3>{thm1} would work. (and for the equation you should  imho also use \label<2>{eq1}  so that it is only on one slide.

Mhm, as far as I can tell, zref-clever is getting the anchor beamer thinks is right for the document. And, for beamer + hyperref, you cannot hope to have better help than the comments of samcarter and Ulrike. ;-)

@UlrikeFischer With \label<2>{eq1} the tag will vanish on the 3rd overlay, which imho looks a bit odd.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry I don't have the time now, need to work on something ;-), but with <2-> you get a destination with the same identifier warning, so that is not good. (beamer's label handling is odd ...).

@UlrikeFischer You should definitely prioritise certain other things :)

@UlrikeFischer The multiply defined labels come from zref-clever using the label hook... Not much I can do, so I added a "known limitation" comment in the manual: https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/commit/e5c03f9f552e58f5a0b0b45f38fb76c54728d70e

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ^^^

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Actually, I was wrong. I don't know why I messed up but the multiply defined labels occur regardless of zref-clever and of mathtools if you use \label<2->{eq1}. What I still don't understand is why showonlyrefs does work for that. Do you get it?

@UlrikeFischer ^^ (I'll revert that commit and think better about this later).

@gusbrs I think showonlyrefs works as expected, with \label{eq1} it will show the label on first overlay where it is created (we just can see it with \setbeamercovered{transparent}). If we force labels on particular overlays, showonlyrefs will show them on these overlays.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz what I don't get is why it works on the third when \label<2->{eq1}.

@gusbrs using a range like <2-> is simply wrong. The definition is quite clear: a range will force the label to be executed more than once. One has to use either \label{blub} or \label<2>{blub}. That the tag disappears is perhaps a problem but if yes it most be resolved in some other way.

@UlrikeFischer Given we get multiply defined labels, I agree there (that's why I reverted the commit). (I'm trying to get why showonlyrefs works for it regarless now). But, I think a "correct" input there would be something like \label<2>{eq1a}\label<3>{eq1b} then \eqref{eq1a}\noeqref{eq1b} or, easier, \zcref{eq1a,eq1b} (which gets compressed into a single ref).

@gusbrs \label<2->{eq1} is more or less the same as \label<2>{eq1}\label<3>{eq1}, so you get a label there as well.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see, makes sense. I presume mathtools won't number an equation that's not labeled since it cannot possibly have been referenced, so that seals the deal. Regardless of what goes on in the .aux file, as long as \label is there for an existing \MT@newlabel{eq1}, showonlyrefs will be satisfied. Understood, thanks!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That said, I must say beamer + overlays/\pause + showonlyrefs is a slippery slope, even if we agree things are "technically working as intended/documented"...

@gusbrs Personally I would do it the other way round: use untagged equations and add tags where needed. This would avoid throwing showonlyrefs into a situation it isn't made for. (preferable with a non-numerical tag to make it better suited for presentations)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That's a good recommendation in this context. But it is tantamount to saying "don't use showonlyrefs with overlays", isn't it? ;-) Well, I was euphemistic too in saying it is a "slippery slope". Let's go with "works as documented, which is not to say as intended". "a situation [showonlyrefs] isn't made for" is a good take too. :-)
